# Random ints and Sorting

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So I'm in AP Computer Science (online class) and our teacher gave us this assignment:
Create a public class named SelectionSort with the following characteristics:

Include a private instance variable that is an array of 100,000 ints.

Include a private instance variable that stores the number of statements run during a sort.

Include a private instance variable that stores the number of statements run during a search.

Create a public mutator method named "sort" which will take an array of ints as an argument, thrown an exception if the array is more than 100,000 elements, store the array as a sorted list using the Selection Sort algorithm otherwise, and count the number of statements which needed to be executed in order to sort the list.

Create a public query method named "linearSearch" which will take an int as a value, search for it using the Linear Search algorithm, and return a String stating either "The integer [int] was not found after executing [count] statements" or "The integer [int] was not found in position [index] after executing [count] statements".

Create a public query method named "binarySearch" which does the same thing as linearSearch but implements the Binary Search algorithm.

Create a public accessor method named "toString" which will return the sorted list as a string with a newline (\n) between each element.

Create a public accessor method named "getSortCount" which will return the number of statements executed to sort the list.

Create a second public class named BubbleSort or InsertionSort, your choice, with the same characteristics except implementing the Bubble Sort or Insertion Sort algorithm.

Create a main tester class with the following characteristics:

Prompt the user for an number between 1 and 100,000 to set the size of the array

Prompt the user for an integer search value between 1 and the size of the array to search for

Generate an array of random numbers with values between 1 and the size of the array

Print the list of random numbers to the screen

Create a SelectionSort object and a BubbleSort or InsertionSort object and pass them the random array for sorting.

Using the objects "getSortCount" accessor method, print two statements to the screen displaying the number of statements executed for each type of sort along the lines of "It took [count] statement executions for a [Selection/Bubble/Insertion] sort".

Search for the search value in each of the objects using both the linearSearch and binarySearch methods.

Print 4 statements to the terminal, two for each type of search on each of the two objects, along the lines of: "Result of [Linear/Binary] search for [search value] in the [Selection/Bubble/Insertion] sort object: [result returned by linearSearch or binarySearch method]"

You will want to build your sort classes and your main tester class slowly and incrementally, using the toString method as a troubleshooting tool, and start with very small arrays (around 10 elements). Once you are convinced your program is working correctly, try incrementally larger and larger arrays and note the results printed to the terminal.

So far I made it to the SelectionSort class. I'm stuck on "Create a public accessor method named "toString" which will return the sorted list as a string with a newline (\n) between each element.
Create a public accessor method named "getSortCount" which will return the number of statements executed to sort the list."

This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


    public class SelectionSort{

    private int stateSort;
    private int stateSearch;
    int fin[] = new int [100000];
    int smallerNumber;
    private int j;
    private int i;
    public boolean Sort(int fin[]){
        if (! (0 <= fin[100000] || fin[100000]>100000)){
        return false;
}
        else{  
                for (int i = 0; i < fin.length - 1; i++) {
                         int index = i;                          
                             for (int j = i + 1; j < fin.length; j++){
                             if (fin[j] < fin[index])
                                 index = j;
                                 int smallerNumber = fin[index]; 
                                 fin[index] = fin[i];
                                 fin[i] = smallerNumber;    
                     }
                    }
    }
    return true;
}
public int getState(){
    return j;
}
int linearSearch (int[] a, int stateSearch){
    for (int i = 0; i <a.length; i++){
         if (a[i] < stateSearch || a[i] > stateSearch){
        System.out.println("The integer" + stateSearch + "was not found after" + a.length +"statements.");
    }
    if(a[i] == stateSearch){
    System.out.println("The integer" + stateSearch + "was found after" + a.length + "statements.");
    return i;
}
} 
return -1;
}
int binarySearch (int[] a, int stateSearch){
    int left = 0;
    int right = a.length - 1;
    while (left <= right){
        int midpoint = (left + right)/2;
        if (a[midpoint] == stateSearch){
        System.out.println("The integer" + stateSearch + "was found after" + a.length + "statements.");
        return midpoint;
    }
        else if (a[midpoint] < stateSearch){
        left = midpoint + 1;
    }
        else{
        right = midpoint - 1;
        System.out.println("The integer" + stateSearch + "was not found after" + a.length +"statements.");
    }
    }
    return -1;
}
public String toString(){
    return stateSearch;
}

}
```

I honestly have no idea where to go from here. Any help?

Comment: what do you mean by stuck?  "Create a public accessor method named "toString" which will return the sorted list as a string with a newline (\n) between each element" is pretty straightforward.  Are you confused about the terminology?

Comment: No, I'm confused about what to return to the statement. He wants me to return a String, but I don't see any strings I can return in my above code.

Comment: Looking at your code, it appears you have a pretty good understanding of what you're doing.  There's functions, variables, loops, strings, and some complex algorithms going on.  And then you say something like "He wants me to return a String, but I don't see any strings I can return in my above code".  It makes me wonder if you even wrote the code that you pasted.  Did you?  But, to actually respond to your question, partially, I will say this:  After implementing one of the sorting algorithms (say bubble), your toString method is trivial.  return Arrays.toString(bubbleSortMyIntegerArray());

Comment: Please explain to me your if statement for the method sort(), the first if statement once you enter the method is if(! (0 <= fin[100000] || fin[100000]>100000)) --- meaning, you want to see if the digit at the 100000 index of fin[] is not greater than/equal to 0 or not greater than 100000.... Why not just have greater than or equal to 0? unless it's a mistake and you meant to say less than or equal to 0

Comment: I'll try what you said. I did write the code myself (obviously with the help of my textbook), thanks!

Comment: Yeah that was a typo by the way :D

Comment: Longest question ever, your probably should do some shortening

Comment: How about you cut out what you have already done correctly, and keep what you are actually worried about?